# Understanding Vim exclusive motion

Tags: vim, text-editor

I refer to : http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#exclusive.
Specifically, the following text:

> Which motions are linewise, inclusive or exclusive is mentioned with the
>   command.  There are however, two general exceptions:
>
> 1. If the motion is exclusive and the end of the motion is in column 1, the
>      end of the motion is moved to the end of the previous line and the motion
>      becomes inclusive.  Example: `}` moves to the first line after a paragraph,
>      but `d}` will not include that line.

Given the following piece of text to start with:

```
This is just a random paragraph.

This is another random paragraph ([S]ome text inside brackets).

This is a third paragraph.
```

I start with my cursor on the character `S`, just after the `(`, in the second paragraph.

I do the following commands - `d}` - in normal mode.  I get the following:

```
This is just a random paragraph.

This is another random paragraph [(]

This is a third paragraph.
```

The cursor is now on the `(` in the second paragraph.  This is expected as per the rule above: `}` is an exclusive motion, that causes the cursor to go to column 1 of the blank line between paragraphs 2 and 3; as per the rule, the cursor goes to the previous line (on the full-stop), and the motion becomes inclusive (the full-stop is deleted as part of the `d` operation).

Let's take the original text again, with the cursor again on the `S`.

If i do the following commands - `d{` - in normal mode, i would expect to get the following, because the `{` is an exclusive motion, and it causes the cursor to go to column 1 of the blank line between paragraphs 1 and 2: everything between the full-stop of paragraph 1 and the `S` are deleted, inclusive.

```
This is just a random paragraphome text inside brackets).

This is a third paragraph.
```

But what actually happens is this:

```
This is just a random paragraph.  
[S]ome text inside brackets).

This is a third paragraph.
```

With the cursor being on the `S`.

Is this an exception to the exception?  Or am i simply getting it all wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important thing to understand about a motion being exclusive is that *the character being excluded is always the character that is furthest towards the end of the buffer*.

When you're going forward it's the character you're jumping to that's excluded, but when you're going backwards it's actually the character under the cursor that's excluded.

Here's your second example illustrated. The part covered by `{` is highlighted in bold.

```
This is just a random paragraph.␤
␤
This is another random paragraph (Some text inside brackets).␤
␤
This is a third paragraph.␤
```

As you can see, the `S` is covered, but it is the rightmost character of the target, and therefore – `{` being an exclusive motion – it is not affected by the operation.

Everything before it including the line feed in the line before it (where `{` lands the cursor) is deleted. And so what you're seeing is indeed what's expected:

```
This is just a random paragraph.␤
Some text inside brackets).␤
␤
This is a third paragraph.␤
```

Comment: Yes this is the 'normal' behaviour.  But as i mentioned at the start of my question, there is an exception to this rule, as noted in the reference manual; else how would you explain the first example i gave (with the "d}")?

Comment: @arunj I think you explained the first example quite well yourself. It's exactly as you explain and as described in the help text you cited. Your question was how example 2 works, or was it not? In any case the 'exception' does apply to the situation in example 1 but not to the situation in example 2.

Comment: This is precisely my confusion...why does the exception not apply to the situation in example 2?  Everything for the rule to apply is there - the motion is exclusive AND the end of the motion is in column 1 (in the blank line).

Comment: @arunj Nope, and that's why I added the highlighting to the first sentence of my answer :) The 'end of the motion' is not in column 1 it is on `S` in column 35.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but that exception doesn't make sense to me; it seems as it is the same as the rule. As quoted on this answer, `When exclusive, the last character towards the end of the buffer is not included.`, and this happens whether the end is on the first column or not -- e.g., `dw` keeps the first character of the next word, `db` keeps the character under the cursor.

Comment: @mMontu You should regard the 'end of the motion' as that end of the motion that is closest towards the end of the buffer; even when that motion causes the cursor to move from right to left, as is the case with `db`!

Comment: @arunj Indeed, that is why I told that the exception seems to indicate the exact same thing as the rule, thus it could be suppressed.

Comment: @mMontu No, because then it would delete the line feed from the line above as well and the result would be different. But this is an academic discussion, and frankly it smells like an implementation detail leaking into userspace.

Answer (score 0):

@glts
After much thought, I think i understand what you are trying to say now.  Basically i was misinterpreting what the manual meant by 'start of motion' and 'end of motion'.  In short, if i understand correctly, the 'start of motion' is always the location nearest to the start of the buffer, and 'end of motion' is the location nearest the end of the buffer, regardless of the 'direction' in which the motion causes the cursor to move!